# Linux: How to delete the original file if the shortcut/link is deleted

Tags: linux

I believe the question is self explanatory so I am gonna make more efficient use of the body section by sharing with you why I asked the question in the first place to  get a better solution than the one I am trying to achieve and get two for one.
Basically I am trying to sync two local directories bi-directionally that respects a kind of .gitignore logic i.e. they are gonna ignore particular files and directories. Better yet, I would love something along the line of whitelisting!
I am familiar with tools like rsync and unison that get the syncing part done but not the ignoring/whitelisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the original file name and delete it when deleting the symlink. For example:

```
rm symlink_name $(readlink -f symlink_name)
```

But remember that if there are other symlinks to the same file, then they'll be dangling.

Comment: I have read the documention about the "f" flag but I am not getting it. Could you kindly tell me why you need to use that as from my testing, I can get the path just fine without it.

Comment: It'll give the canonicalized path name (e.g resolving all relative paths & symlinks). For example, if the `symlink_name` points to *another* link then without `-f` you'd get that symlink's name. With `-f`, you'd get actual file name with all symlinks resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Links pointing to links! Don't think I'll be needing that. :D